# WordPress Database Connection Error on MacOS Mojave

Tags: mysql, wordpress, macos-mojave

After updating to MacOS Mojave, I installed WordPress locally with [WordPressify](https://www.wordpressify.co/)

I installed the latest version of MySQL and added a database via MySQLWorkbench.

MySQL was up and running. Everything seemed to be working. Running the development server launched the WordPress initial configuration page. Database credentials were correct. Still, WordPress was unable to connect to the database.

Comment: is this still an open question? If not, you may well delete it or if you think is worth it, write an answer yourself.

Comment: I found the solution and posted it, just in case anyone else experiences the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First step to solving this was to enable debugging in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

This revealed that the database was running, but the authentication method was failing. This was solved in **System Preferences**... **MySQL**... **Initialize Database**
and selecting **Use Legacy Password Encryption**.

Hope this helps!